# WCF - solution architecture

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I am working on a project in which a WCF service will be consumed by iOS apps. The number of hits expected on the webserver at any given point in time is around 900-1000. Every request may take 1-2 seconds to complete. The same number of requests are expected on every second 24/7.

This is what my plan:

1. Write WCF RESTful service (the instance context mode will be percall).
2. Request/Response will be in Json.
3. There are some information that needs to be persisted in the server - this information is actually received from another remote system - which is shared among all the requests. Since using a database may not be a good idea (response time is very important - 2 seconds is the max the customer can wait), would it be good to keep it in server memory (say a static Dictionary - assume this dictionary will be a collection of 150000 objects - each object consists of 5-7 string types and their keys). I know, this is volatile!
4. Each request will spawn a new thread (by using Threading.Timers) to do some cleanup - this thread will do some database read/write as well.

Now, if there is a load balancer introduced sometime later, the in-memory stored objects cannot be shared between requests routed through another node - any ideas?

I hope you gurus could help me by throwing your comments/suggestions on the entire architecture, WCF throttling, object state persistence etc. Please provide some pointers on the required Hardware as well. We plan to use Windows 2008 Enterprise Edition server, IIS  and SQL Server 2008 Std edition database.

Adding more t #3:
As I said, we get some information to the service from a remote system. On the web server where the the WCF is hosted, a client of the remote system will be installed and WCF references one of this client dlls to get the information, in the form of a hashtable(that method returns a hashtable - around 150000 objects will be there in this collection). Would you suggest writing this information to the database, and the iOS requests (on every second) which reach the service retrieves this information from the database directly? Would it perform better than consuming directly from this hashtable if this is made static?

Comment: If you introduce a load balancer I'd stick to a shared nothing architecture.

Comment: I'd also use a caching platform like Velocity rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Windows Server 2008 I would definitely use the Windows Server App Fabric Cache to store your state:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383813.aspx

It is free to use, well supported and integrated and is (more or less) API compatible with the Windows Azure App Fabric Cache if you every shift your service to Azure. In our company (disclaimer: not my team) we used to use MemCache but changed to the App Fabirc Cache and don't regret it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me throw some comments/suggestions based on my experience in serving a similar amount or request under the WCF framework, 3.5 back in the days.

I don't agree to #3. Using a database here is the right thing to do. To address response time, implement **caching** and possibly `cache dependency` in order to keep the data synchronized across all instances (assuming that you are load balanced)(also see App Fabric suggested above/below). In real world scenarios, data changes, often, and you must minimize the impact.

We used Barracuda hardware and software to handle scalability as far as I can tell.

Consider **indexing** `keys/values` with Lucene if applicable. Lucene delivers extremely good performances when it comes to read/write. Do not use it to store your entire data, read on it. A life saver if used correctly. Note that it could be complicated to implement on a load balanced environment.

Basically, caching might be the only necessary change to your architecture.

Comment: +1 for against #3, and what if the the service crashed for some reason? bye bye 150000 objects

Comment: @MikeGoodwin thought App Fabric was Azure only and was $$$. Nice to know, I'll definitely give it a try someday!

Comment: @maxbeaudoin: I think the general direction of travel is for the Windows Server App Fabric and the Azure App Fabric to converge where it makes sense, at least at the API level. Obviously they will be different at the binary level.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin I wanted to find an alternative to the codeplex AspProviders cloud solution to session, membership, cache, etc and stumbled upon AppFabric which at the time was more or less released. I had an Azure project and the client didn't want to pay for more cloud services so... Nice to know yep! We don't do much balanced web apps so I'll see if it can be usefull in any other way.